# Memory corruption attacks in c

Tags: c, security, pointers

I am reading [this article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/icp.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=6547101#sec3).

It's about how attackers can produce memory errors (dangling pointers and pointers going out of memory) that lead to memory corruption and possible attack on the program/system.

Different methods are being described as well how to make programs more memory safe and prevent those attacks.

However I have difficulties understanding some things. I thought I have some fair knowledge of C (pointers, dangling pointers, memory allocation, data encapsulation, and couple of things more) but reading that article makes me question my knowledge of C. And those couple of C sources I have had and the reading I have done have not pointed out those vulnerabilities.

How can an attacker take control of my programs pointers? I read that it's connected with dangling pointers or pointers gone out of memory or double freeing, but how? And how does one know what to look for?

For example if I take care of dangling pointers:

```
int *ptr = malloc(1000 * sizeof *ptr);
// Do some stuff here
free(ptr);
ptr = NULL;
```

Can an attacker still take control?

And then the authors point to `printf(user_input) // input "%3$x" prints 3rd integer on the stack` as a printf format string bug. What does this mean?
I'd really like to know how it works.

And I was wondering as well if unit testing, mocking and stubbing can also help to make programs more memory safe by pointing out some possible places where errors can happen.

How can I assure my code is safe with simple tools and knowledge?

Comment: The first line of defense is not to leave any vulnerabilities. Do not *let* anyone enter a string that is too long. Do not *use* any input string as a format string. Check the *range* of any number input. Check the return value of every function, in particular I/O functions. Never rely on input data being what you expect it to be. And so on.

Comment: zero out the memory before freeing it may help, but I'm not sure how you would guarantee it levels lower than glibc

Comment: With your example "if I take care of dangling pointers", the only answer that can be given to the question "can an attacker still take control" is "it depends".  It depends on what is done in the `// Do some stuff here` code, and on what is done in the code after `ptr = NULL;`, and it might depend on what is done before the memory is allocated.  Mistakes in any of those three locations could mean that the attacker can still take control.  If there are no mistakes in any of those sections, then the attacker won't be able to take control. That, unfortunately, is characteristic of such questions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - As I understand, taking care of a dangling pointer is half of the stroy. I'm not quite sure how to ask a more specific question due to my lack of knowledge. However, It's still unclear to me, how an attacker can take control, wether it's a dangling pointer or not. Can you give me some simple examples.

Comment: If you don't make mistakes in the code before and after this fragment, and the `// Do some stuff` part doesn't do anything untoward then things are safe enough as shown, but you have to deal with the whole program.